# How to store files on amazon S3 conditionally based on what environment you are in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, paperclip, development-environment

I'm using Paperclip, and this code, along with the `aws-s3` gem, allows me to store file uploads with Amazon S3:

```
has_attached_file :photo,
  :styles => {
    :tiny => "25x25#",
    :shown => "40x40#",
    :thumbnail => "50x50#",
    :small  => "150x150>",
    :medium => "300x300>" },
    :default_url => "/images/default_:style.jpg",
    :storage => :s3, 
    :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml",
    :path => "profile/:attachment/:style/:id.:extension"
```

However I do not want to store files on Amazon S3 when I am in my development environment. How do I set that in my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could probably do something like

```
:storage => Rails.env.production? ? :s3 : :whatever
```

Comment: what should `:whatever` be? because normally I would just leave out `:storage` if I didn't want to store files on s3...

Comment: Could be :filesystem, which should make it save as files locally

Comment: also, if I'm storing the files locally in development, will these files be pushed to heroku along with my application?

Answer (score 1):

In the end of environment.rb:

```
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root.to_s}/config/config.yml")[Rails.env]
```

In config/config.yml:

```
development:
  use_amazon: false

test:
  use_amazon: false

production:
  use_amazon: true
```

And in your controller:

```
if APP_CONFIG['use_amazon']
   #USING AMAZON S3
else
   #USING SOMETHING ELSE
end
```

This should work.
Good Luck!